# Does Yarn require installation of Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I want to use Yarn as a package manager for my project. To install Yarn and use it, is it compulsory to have Node on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

Yarn is a package manager *for Node*. It competes with NPM, not Node; both require Node.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/

> It is recommended to install Yarn through the npm package manager, which comes bundled with Node.js when you install it on your system.